# Помогите в использовании QTimer

Tags: c++, qt

Почему ругается? Гуглил, не могу найти ответа.
Слот описал, метод описал, связать не получается.. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_overflow()));
```

> C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\Test\map.cpp:18: ошибка: no matching function
>   for call to 'QObject::connect(QTimer*&, const char*, Map*, const
>   char*)'
>        QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_overflow()));

Пытаюсь коннект выполнить в своем классе map.cpp:

```
#include "map.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QLabel>

Map::Map(int height, int weight){

}

void Map::timer_overflow(){

     timer->stop();
}

void Map::move(QLabel *_hero){
    hero=_hero;
    timer = new QTimer;

    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_overflow()));

    timer->start(110);

}
void Map::initialize(int i, int j, QPushButton *btn){
    massMap[i][j]=btn;
}

Map::~Map(){

}
```

Собственно, вот map.h:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QTimer>

class Map{

    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void timer_overflow();

public:

    struct coordinate{
        int _x,_y;
    };

    QLabel *hero;
    QTimer *timer;
    QPushButton *massMap[5][5];
    Map(int height, int weight);
    ~Map();

    void move(QLabel *hero);
    void initialize(int i, int j, QPushButton *btn);

};

#endif // MAP_H
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реализации механизма сигналов и слотов, необходимо, чтобы ваш класс был наследником **QObject** и имел макрос **Q_OBJECT**. Также вам необходимо запустить **qmake** во вкладке **Сборка** (QtCreator).  Подробнее вы можете прочитать по ссылкам:

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/50812/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/141983/
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Ваш же код должен выглядеть вот так:

map.h

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QTimer>
class Map: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    struct coordinate{
        int _x,_y;
    };

    QLabel *hero;
    QTimer *timer;
    QPushButton *massMap[5][5];

    Map(int height, int weight, QObject * parent = 0);
    ~Map();

    void move(QLabel *hero);
    void initialize(int i, int j, QPushButton *btn);

public slots:
    void timer_overflow();

};

#endif // MAP_H
```

map.cpp

```
#include "map.h"

Map::Map(int height, int weight, QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Конструктор класса Map" << height << weight;
}


void Map::timer_overflow(){

    timer->stop();
}

void Map::move(QLabel *_hero)
{
    hero = _hero;
    timer = new QTimer;

    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_overflow()));

    timer->start(110);
}

void Map::initialize(int i, int j, QPushButton *btn)
{
    massMap[i][j] = btn;
}

Map::~Map()
{

}
```

Comment: Использую ваш код для map.cpp и map.h

Компилятор выдает ошибку: C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\Test\map.cpp:3: ошибка: undefined reference to `vtable for Map' 

и  C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\Test\map.cpp:29: ошибка: undefined reference to `vtable for Map'

Ссылается на строку Конструктора и на Строку Десктруктора

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков qmake должен помочь

Comment: Не подскажете где его включить?
У меня есть "использовать jom вместо nmake"

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков Вкладка Сборка->Запустить qmake

Comment: А как мне теперь создать объект класса? На  Map s(3, 3); ругается, C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\Test\mainwindow.cpp:12: ошибка: call of overloaded 'Map(int, int)' is ambiguous
     Map s(3, 3);
               ^

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков в моем коде в файле map.h был лишний конструктор Map(int height, int weight);. код поправил

Comment: Спасибо, большое, вроде бы работает. Не подскажите, что изменилось после запуска qmake? Он использует другой компилятор?

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков заново сгенерировались правила сборки. Если какой-нибудь из предложенных ответов вас устроил, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка слева от текста).

Comment: `explicit` для конструктора с 2+ аргументами не нужен, если Вы конечно не пытались запретить создание с помощью одних `{}`

Comment: @ixSci не пытался, убрал

Answer (score 3):

И источник и приёмник сигналов должен наследоваться от `QObject` и иметь макрос `Q_OBJECT`. Это если использовать старый синтаксис, если это Qt5, то можно воспользоваться новым синтаксисом:

```
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]{timer_overflow();});
```

Comment: Исправил на : QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]{timer_overflow();});   

Все равно ругается:
C:\Users\Vesbat\Desktop\Test\map.cpp:19: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QTimer*&, void (QTimer::*)(QTimer::QPrivateSignal), Map::move(QLabel*)::<lambda()>)'
     QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this]{timer_overflow();});
                                                                        ^

Comment: Если я отнаследую класс Map от класса QObject, я тогда не смогу для Map указать собственный конструктор?

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков, тот код, что я указал, должен собираться и работать — не должно быть ошибок, у Вас точно Qt5? Если Вы унаследуетесь от `QObject`, никто Вам не запретит иметь собственный конструктор

Comment: В "о программе": Qt Creator 3.6.0   Основан на Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 бита)

Я только исправил свою строку на Вашу, макрос Q_OBJECT был изначально подключен. Ругается.

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков, это QtCreator, а какой toolbox используется? Tools->Options->Build&Run-> Qt Versions

Comment: Qt 5.5.1 MinGW 32bit

Comment: @ДмитрийПоляков, я только что проверил — мой код компилируется, а вот Ваш не может быть собран. То, что Вы привели в вопросе не соберётся, даже если убрать `connect`, потому что либо нужно наследоваться от `QObject`, определять `Q_OBJECT` и тогда можно будет пользоваться `public slots:`, в противном случае будет ошибка, если хотя бы одно из этих условий нарушено.

Comment: Связывание через указатель на функцию вместо использования макросов `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` конечно лучше, т.к. переносит проверку связей на этап компиляции, но в случае наличия перегруженных функций код принимает довольно жуткий вид.